# Access Violation (0xC0000005) NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, limit, memory-access

I have this simple NumPy/Python code below:

```py
from numpy import zeros, float32

v = 3039345
d = 400
i = 354993
j = 0

var1 = zeros((v,d), dtype=float32)
var1[i, j] = 0 #the problem pops here
```

when the last line is interpreted, I have this:

> ```
> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
> ```

If i < 354993 the execution is fine. I am using Python 2.7 32-bit over Windows 8 64-bit. It is due to a limit in Memory? in this case what would be the best solution to have this working?

Comment: For me it doesn't crash (Python3.5 Windows 8.1 64 bits)

Comment: Hey, are you using 64-bit python as well?

Comment: Yes, 64bit python3, `Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` to be exact

Comment: 32bit python2.7 fails on my machine `Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` with access violation: `Unhandled exception at 0x1000696C (multiarray.pyd) in python2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x40029260.`

Comment: I suspect the reason is the array size is greater than 2**32 measured in bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the 32 bit version of numpy binaries. Numpy does calculate the size of the allocated memory region using platform-specific integers, and the size of the array measured in bytes does not fit in 2**32. It sounds like a bug, as it should raise an error at array creation in my opinion.

You can install 64 bit version of any python and numpy, and that will fix your problem.